# Would the compiler optimize this expression into a temporary constant rather than resolve it every iteration?

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, expression

I have the following loop:

```
for (unique_ptr<Surface>& child : Children)
{
    child->Gather(hit);

    if (hit && HitTestMode == HitTestMode::Content && child->MouseOver && !mouseOver)
    {
        mouseOver = true;
    }
}
```

I wonder if the compiler (I use Visual Studio 2013, targeting x64 on Win7 upwards) would optimize the expression

```
hit && HitTestMode == HitTestMode::Content
```

into a temporary constant and use that rather than resolve the expression every iteration, similar to me doing something like this:

```
bool contentMode = hit && HitTestMode == HitTestMode::Content;

for (unique_ptr<Surface>& child : Children)
{
    child->Gather(hit);

    if (contentMode && child->MouseOver && !mouseOver)
    {
        mouseOver = true;
    }
}
```

*Bonus question:*

*Is checking for `!mouseOver` worth it (in order to skip the conditional `mouseOver = true;` if it has already been set)? Or is it faster to simply set it again regardless?*

Comment: Probably not. Look into generated assembly code (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) use `g++ -O -fverbose-asm -S`). Regarding performance, benchmark! (I think it is faster to simply set `mouseOver` again regardless)

Comment: answer to bonus question: it's faster to just set it again. I would add a break statement after assigning because that way you wouldn't have to go through the rest of the children.

Comment: @programmerjake Thanks. I can't break, though, because there's an operation that needs to be performed on each child regardless (that I left out of my original example - I will update it to include this now).

Comment: Here's a fun post on why if-statements can be expensive:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/131930

Comment: @d7samurai What's a _"Bonus question"_ actually? Could you elaborate on this please? You're supposed to ask **one** question per question, and you can't give any bonuses for anyone on answers. Please stop that. You may rather ask another (related) question. Also for a better practice you shouldn't care about such things for micro-optimisation, unless you'll notice any real problems. Just let it go, and be productive instead.

Comment: @d7samurai _"Would you be happier if it instead said "by the way..."?"_ Well, no. It's a different question from your original one. As mentioned: **one** question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, it's a footnote, an apropos to the code, secondary, not warranting a separate question.. And as you can see, it has already been answered in a similarly secondary fashion - via a comment, rather than as an Answer. Calm down.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this. You can compile in release mode with debug info and take a look at the disassembly. I'd try it but don't have time at the moment.

Comment: @NeilKirk See below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to whether that optimization could even take place would depend on what `hit`, `HitTestMode` and `HitTestMode::Content` are and whether it's possible that they could be changed by the call to `child->Gather()`.

If those identifiers are constants or local variables that the compiler can prove aren't modified, then it's entirely possible that the sub-expression `hit && HitTestMode == HitTestMode::Content` will be hoisted.

For example, consider the following compilable version of your example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Surface
{
public:
    void Gather(bool hit);
    bool MouseOver;
};

enum class HitTestMode
{
    Content = 1,
    Foo = 3,
    Bar = 4,
};


extern HitTestMode hittestmode;

bool anyMiceOver( vector<unique_ptr<Surface> > & Children, bool hit)
{
    bool mouseOver = false;

    for (unique_ptr<Surface>& child : Children)
    {
        child->Gather(hit);

        if (hit && hittestmode == HitTestMode::Content && child->MouseOver && !mouseOver)
        {
            mouseOver = true;
        }
    }

    return mouseOver;
}
```

When compiled using g++ 4.8.1 (mingw) with the -O3 optimization option, you get the following snippet of code for the loop (annotations added):

```
    mov rbx, QWORD PTR [rcx]      ; Children.begin()
    mov rsi, QWORD PTR 8[rcx]     ; Children.end()
    cmp rbx, rsi                 
    je  .L8                       ; early exit if Children is empty

    test    dl, dl                ; hit == 0?
    movzx   edi, dl
    je  .L5                       ; then goto loop L5

    xor ebp, ebp
    mov r12d, 1
    jmp .L7
    .p2align 4,,10
.L6:
    add rbx, 8
    cmp rsi, rbx                  ; check for end of Children
    je  .L2
.L7:
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rbx]
    mov edx, edi
    call    _ZN7Surface6GatherEb  ; call child->Gather(hit)
    cmp DWORD PTR hittestmode[rip], 1  ; check hittestmode
    jne .L6
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]      ; check child->MouseOver
    cmp BYTE PTR [rax], 0
    cmovne  ebp, r12d             ; set mouseOver appropriately
    jmp .L6
    .p2align 4,,10

.L5:                             ; loop L5 is run only when hit == 0
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rbx]     ; get net element in Children
    mov edx, edi
    add rbx, 8
    call    _ZN7Surface6GatherEb ; call child->Gather(hit)
    cmp rsi, rbx
    jne .L5

.L8:
    xor ebp, ebp
.L2:
    mov eax, ebp
    add rsp, 32
    pop rbx
    pop rsi
    pop rdi
    pop rbp
    pop r12
    ret
```

You'll note that the check for `hit` has been hoisted out of the loop - and if it's `false` then the a loop that does nothing but call `child->Gather()` is run.

If `hitmodetest` is changed to be a variable that's passed as a function argument so it's no longer subject to possibly being changed by the call to `child-Gather(hit)`, then the compiler will also hoist the check for the value of `hittestmode` out of the loop and jump to the loop that does nothing but call `child->Gather()`.

With a local `hittestmode` using `-O2` will calculate `hit && hittestmode == HitTestMode::Content` prior to the loop and stash that result in a register, but it will still test the register in each loop iteration instead of optimizing to a separate loops that don't even bother with the test.

Since you specifically asked about the VS2013 compiler (using `/Ox` and `/Ot` options), it doesn't seem to hoist or optimize either of the checks (for `hit` or `hittestmode`) out of the loop - all it seems to do is keep the values for those variable in registers.

Comment: For our practical purposes here, your compilable example encapsulates exactly the way the actual implementation is structured, so your analysis is right on the money. Since I know something that the compiler doesn't (that `HitTestMode` isn't touched by `child->Gather()`) I can take the liberty of collapsing and moving them out of the loop. However, your answer has made me realize that I might _want_ `child->Gather()` to be able to [hackily] alter `HitTestMode` during iteration and therefore leave the expression in, "unhoisted".. Disappointing that VS doesn't hoist anything here, though.